# Is it correct to use "thus" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

I'm not sure If I can use "thus" in the following sentence. Does it mean "in this way" or "with this result"?

> She was lucky enough to learn from all those movies, **thus** raising
> the quality of her own one.

Comment: "thereby" perhaps?

Comment: @JamesK, The OP is not asking for an alternative word. The question is about the applicability of "thus" to the given context.

Comment: I believe "this" is ok here. A lot of the time "in this way" could replace it.

Comment: @BeatsMe I know.  That is why I didn't answer the question. I'm asking if the OP has considered this alternative. If they have they can include that in their question.  If not it might provoke some lateral thinking.  But a comment isn't meant to be an answer; my comment doesn't attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, you can use "thus" in the sentence "She was lucky enough to learn from all those movies, thus raising the quality of her own one."
2. Yes, two of the main meanings of "thus" are either "in this way" or "with this result" (or maybe "because of this" would be a better substitute for the second use). The first one makes sense in this sentence:

> She was lucky enough to learn from all those movies, **in this way** raising the quality of her own one.

An example of the second use might be something like:

> She learned a lot from all those movies; **thus** [*because of this*], she raised the quality of her own.